# how to convert this line into vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, anonymous-types

from the free dinner book for asp.net MVC

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection formValues) {
    Dinner dinner = dinnerRepository.GetDinner(id);
    UpdateModel(dinner);
    dinnerRepository.Save();
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = dinner.DinnerID });
}
```

how to convert this line into vb.net?

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = dinner.DinnerID });
```

more the **new { id = dinner.DinnerID }** part

thanks

Comment: Probably would be nice to know what's the signature of RedirectToAction

Comment: @gbianchi, I'm following 100% of what is said in the pdf but doing it into vb.net

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
Return RedirectToAction("Details", New With { .id = dinner.DinnerID})
```

In VB the anonymous type declaration syntax, as well as normal object initializers, needs a "." prefix on all of the property names.  This is consistent with other VB features such as the With context.

Comment: @Norldorin, hah. At least I didn't mispell it!

Comment: We are programmers not spelling bee champs... heck even I want to beat up those nerds ;)

Answer (score 2):

That is using an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc468406.aspx), so it will look like this:

```
Return RedirectToAction("Details", New With { .id = dinner.DinnerID })
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Return RedirectToAction("Details", New With { .id = dinner.DinnerID })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
New With {.id = dinner.DinnerID}
```